# Is the angle between a vector and a line defined?

Tags: vector-spaces, definition

> Is the angle between a vector and a line defined?

The angle between two lines $a,b$ is defined as the smallest of the angles created.

The angle between two vectors $\vec{a},\vec{b}$ is the smallest angle one of them has to be rotated by so that the directions of $\vec{a},\vec{b}$ are the same.

I have not yet found a definition of the angle between a vector and a line, which makes me wonder if, and if so, how, it is defined.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The question what is the "right" definition here really depends on what the definition of angle between two vectors is. I am not sure which one is meant in the question but it does not matter for the answer in some sense.

There are (at least) two definitions for the angle between two vectors (in the plane), the non-oriented (or unsigned) angle and the oriented (or signed) angle. Both have some merit and relevance.

Depending on which one of the two one choses  for vectors one should in my opinion choose ones definition of angle between a line and a vector, as follows:

> The angle between a vector $\vec{v}$ and a line $L$  is the smaller of *the angles* between $\vec{v}$ and $\vec{u}$, and $\vec{v}$ and $-\vec{u}$ where $\vec{u}$ is a vetor directing $L$.

Here *the angles* is to be taken **in the same sense as it is taken for two vectors.** Or rather one might define a non-oriented angle and an oriented angle between a vector and a line if one cares about the distinction.

The definition of "angle" in the question is not compltely precise, so it is hard to tell. But it seems to me that rather the non-oriented angle is meant.

---

This is not much different from rschwieb's answer, which I upvoted, but the comment thread suggested there is some need for clarification.

Answer (score 1):

You could just take a vector pointing along the direction of the line and use the angle between the original vector and this vector.

Of course, you would need to choose the orientation your new vector should point: this will affect the angle you get. I would expect you would choose the one which minimizes the angle.

Comment: To formalize: Let $P$ and $Q$ be distinct points of the line $L$; let $v = (Q - P) / \| Q - P \|$. We call $v$ a *direction vector* for the line $L$. Evidently, the only possible direction vectors are $v$ and $-v$. reschwieb's answer can then be recast with disambiguation as something like "The angle from $L$ to a vector $w$ is the smaller of the angles from $v$ or $-v$ to $w$". But if $L$ is an oriented line (so that one of $v$ or $-v$ is preferred), then the angle would be "the angle from the preferred direction vector to $w$."

Comment: "You would choose the one which minimizes the angle." Source or proof? I could've guessed this myself, but I want to know this for sure.

Comment: @mathh I don't have a source: I'm just using my common sense. One does not provide proofs for definitions, either, so I don't have anything like that either. I can't imagine another definition more compatible with our intuition. Regards.

Comment: @rschwieb When you're defining the angle between the $Ox$ axis (an infinite vector) and a line, it could easily make more sense to define the angle as the shortest angle the axis should be rotated counter-clockwise so that the axis is collinear to the line (because this is the angle $\theta$ such that $\tan\theta = m$, where $m$ is the slope of the line).

Comment: @mathh One could make that convention, but the other one doesn't require making the clockwise-counterclockwise decision. (What do you mean by "infinite vector" by the way? Are you thinking of a *ray*?)

Comment: @rschwieb "..the other one.." You mean yours? And what desicion are you talking about? Just rotate the vector counter-clockwise until the vector is collinear to the line and this angle is, according to my definition, the angle between the line and the vector, and I've shown you why this definition is useful. As for the other question, a line is to a segment what an axis is to a vector - the difference is that it has infinite length.

Comment: @mathh `"..the other one.." You mean yours?` Right. `a line is to a segment what an axis is to a vector` I don't follow this analogy, but if it's not important we need not pursue it. `the difference is that it has infinite length` I can tell you are describing something that is like a vector but isn't a vector. That's fine, it's just not a formal terminology that I'm familiar with.

Comment: @mathh `And what desicion are you talking about?` I mean the *choice* of "counterclockwise." The main drawback with baking in that *everything will be measured counterclockwise* by fiat is that angle won't be left invariant after something as simple as a reflection. It will be invariant if you choose the minimum, though.

Comment: @rschwieb "is that angle won't be left invariant" The definition might not be too useful if you want the invariance to hold, but such a definition would let you generally say: "the tangent of the angle between the axis and the line is equal to the slope of the line", and your definition doesn't let me claim this statement which looks reasonably useful.

Comment: @mathh Yep, it's just a matter of context where the different definitions will be useful. I'm not saying the counterclockwise definition isn't useful, I'm just pointing out a drawback it has in my favorite context. Personally, I like to be free of coordinates and axes where possible, and just work with the abstract vectors. Things that aren't invariant under elementary isometries (like slope) do not concern me a whole lot, but they are useful for learning coordinate geometry.